# search through JSON Object for specific key

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting a JSON response from an API provider which I can't change, and there are lots of nested objects in the response and then there is an object which I need, below is just the example of response actual response has a lot of nested objects and then the match object,

I can easily access the match object but in some case, the API provider add some more object above it as shown in the 2nd response where he added the group and then there is match object which I need,

still by using some if, else we can get through it.

but are there any methods or ways available that can directly give me access to the match object or can find the match object?

I'm using laravel 5.8

and tried some of the collection methods none of them work on objects.

in actual response, I have to go 7 steps nested.

```
//1nd API response
[{
  "version": "2.258.2",
  "sport": "badminton",
  "lang": "en",
   "generated_utc": "2021-07-28T13:58:16+00:00",
  "method": {
    "method_id": "258",
    "name": "get_matches"
    "match" : {
       score_a:0,
       score_b:1
     }
  }
}]

//2nd API response
[{
  "version": "2.258.2",
  "sport": "badminton",
  "lang": "en",
   "generated_utc": "2021-07-28T13:58:16+00:00",
  "method": {
    "method_id": "258",
    "name": "get_matches"
    "group":{
      "match" : {
       score_a:0,
       score_b:1
     }
    }
  }
}]
```

Thank You!

Comment: Collection methods don't work on objects directly, but you can turn objects into collections using `collect($object);`

Comment: yes, I'm doing it, but there are only objects not array in my response, I'm getting a single element in a array

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the code you've already tried to it ([mcve])?

Comment: convert it as array and use the key_exist('match',$array) php method to evaluate if the fetched data came with the desired key